# C# - HttpWebResponse redirect checker

Tags: c#, redirect, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to code a redirect checker, the solution I have was just banged together this morning so it's not the most efficient but it does everything I need it to do apart from one thing:

It only ever checks two sites before stopping, no errors occur, it just stops on the "request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;" line for the third page.

I've tried using different sites and changing the combination of pages to check but it only ever checks two.

Any ideas?

```
        string URLs = "/htmldom/default.asp/htmldom/dom_intro.asp/htmldom/dom_examples2.asp/xpath/default.asp";
        string sURL = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
        string[] u = Regex.Split(URLs, ".asp");

        foreach (String site in u)
        {
            String superURL = sURL + site + ".asp";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(superURL);

            request.Method = "HEAD";
            request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

            var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            String a = response.GetResponseHeader("Location");

            Console.WriteLine("Site: " + site + "\nResponse Type: " + response.StatusCode + "\nRedirect page" + a + "\n\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aside from the fact that it will break if a `WebException` is ever thrown, I believe the reason it's just stopping is that you never dispose of your response. If you have multiple URLs served actually by the same site, they'll use a connection pool - and by not disposing of the response, you're not releasing the connection. You should use:

```
using (var response = request.GetResponse())
{
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) response;
    // Use httpResponse here
}
```

Note that I'm casting here instead of using `as` - if the response *isn't* an `HttpWebResponse`, an `InvalidCastException` on that line is more informative than a `NullReferenceException` on the next line...

Comment: Thanks Jon, after putting in some error handling code, your solution worked perfectly